# Загрузить библиотеки, и лишь затем выполнить функцию

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Необходимо полностью  загрузить скрипты, и лишь затем выполнить функцию. Текущий вариант не работает. Какие необходимо внести правки?

```
if (Type == '1') {
    var getAnimation_1 = $.getScript('{0}/animation/1.js'.format(s.scripts));
    $.when(getAnimation_1).then(animation);
};

if (Type == '2') {
    var getAnimation_1 = $.getScript('{0}/animation/1.js'.format(s.scripts));
    $.when(getAnimation_1).then(animation);
};
```

Comment: Ваш код верен, если в переменной animation ссылка на функцию, которая должна выполняться после загрузки. А вот вопрос вы могли бы раскрыть полнее: в чем проблема? Где код функции? Что такое .format?

Comment: format просто преобразует url(к задаче отоношения не имеет). Но Функция animation(может быть любая другая в данном случае роли не играет) запускается до полной загрузки скрипта(1.js) - в результате выбивается стандартная ошибка переменная is not defined. При дебаге и установки breakpointa на текущие строчки скрипт успевает загрузится и функция выполнятся нормально.

Comment: Простите, но я уверен, что вы неверно толкуете симптомы. Ваш код верен. Возможно, переменная не определена по другой причине? Скоуп недоступен? Прошу вас провести еще одну проверку: один console.log('a') внутри загружаемого скрипта, другой console.log('b') - в функции animation.

Comment: Спасибо, вы правы - у меня была ошибка, функция повторно вызывалась в другом месте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я крайне редко использую конструкцию $when().then() и, обычно, придерживаюсь более консервативных методов работы, поэтому могу не знать о подводных камнях этого способа. Но предложенный ниже код 100% сработает так, как вы ожидаете - функция выполнится только после загрузки скрипта:

```
$.getScript('{0}/animation/1.js'.format(s.scripts), animation);
```

или

```
$.getScript('{0}/animation/1.js'.format(s.scripts), function(){
    //do something
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, нашел ошибку